# Flutter checkbox not deselecting after select

Tags: flutter, radio-button, radio-group, radiobuttonlist

I have an API with an array list of values that passes values to my Radio button successfully. When I select each the select value parses but I'm unable to deselect the select radio button. Below is my flutter code:

```
ListView.builder(    shrinkWrap:true,
                     physics:const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                     itemCount:dataOptions == null? 0: dataOptions.length,
                     itemBuilder:(BuildContext context,int index) {
                                                            return Container(
                                                                padding:
                                                                    const EdgeInsets
                                                                            .only(
                                                                        bottom:
                                                                            0.0),
                                                                child: Card(
                                                                  elevation: 0,
                                                                    child:
                                                                        ListTile(
                                                                  title: Text(
                                                                      dataOptions[index]['option_title']),
                                                                  leading:
                                                                      Radio(
                                                                    value: dataOptions[index]["option_price"],

                                                                        //below will be the default value.
                                                                        groupValue: dataOptions[index]["option_id"],
                                                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                                                      setState(
                                                                          () {
                                                                            dataOptions[index]["option_id"] = value;
                                                                        debugPrint("radioSel:$value");
                                                                      });
                                                                    },
                                                                    activeColor: Colors.green,
                                                                  ),
                                                                  trailing:
                                                                      Text(dataOptions[index]['option_price'].toString(), style:TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                                                      color: colorPink, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                                    ),
                                                                  ),
                                                                )));
                                                          })
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve.
Do you want to be able to select multiple Radio buttons at once and deselect them?
Or do you want to always select one at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `groupValue` stores the currently selected value and you use the individual `dataOptions[index]["option_id"]` as `groupValue` all radio buttons are independent from each other.

If this is intended, check out checkboxes as they are meant to be used for this behavior.  [CheckBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox-class.html)

To deselect a `Radio` widget if another one in the group is selected do the following.

```
//Set default option if prefered
String? _groupValue;

Radio(
  value: dataOptions[index]["option_price"],
  groupValue: _groupValue,
  onChanged: (value) {
    setState(() {
      _groupValue = value;
    });
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this and it worked.

toggleable: true,

reference: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio/toggleable.html